# Create an SSL connection to my API on EC2 Instance using a load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, ssl, amazon-ec2

I have an API that I created on an ec2 instance. Call it with an http and it works and responds well:

http://ec2 .... us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/api ...

I have an Application Load Balancer with a target group that is for that ec2 instance and the current target group status is healthy.

I am trying to make a secure connection to the api using the load balancer however I get a 404 error.

My goal is to be able to use the API via the SSL enabled load balancer. I am not sure what configuration is missing. Any ideas?

Comment: A 404 "not found" error would be coming from your application running on the EC2 instance. You need to look at your application logs to see why it is returning a 404.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Amazon Certificate Manager and then [follow some steps](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/associate-acm-certificate-alb-nlb/) to use an SSL certificate.

Comment: I already have ACM and its installed on the load balancer, the issue is I cannot make an api request via the load balancer